# XAML Grid Columns Width

Tags: c#, xaml, win-universal-app

I have problem with *Grid* container as it doesn't work as I saw in some old tutorials.

I have following XAML:

```
<UserControl
    x:Class="UWA.Views.LastActivities"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="using:UWA.Views"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    d:DesignHeight="300"
    d:DesignWidth="400">
    <UserControl.Resources>
        <DataTemplate x:Key="FullItem">
            <Grid HorizontalAlignment="Center">
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                    <ColumnDefinition />
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition />
                    <RowDefinition />
                    <RowDefinition />
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>

                <Image x:Name="icon" Grid.Row="0" Grid.RowSpan="3" Grid.Column="0" Height="45" Width="45" VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="5" Source="ms-appx:///Assets/Square44x44Logo.png"/>

                <TextBlock x:Name="title" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="{Binding Title, FallbackValue=Title}" Margin="3,0,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Center" FontWeight="Bold" FontSize="21.333" />
                <TextBlock x:Name="description" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="{Binding Description, FallbackValue=Description}" Margin="3,0,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Center" FontSize="18.667" FontWeight="Bold" Foreground="#FF838383" />
                <TextBlock x:Name="content" Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="1" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="{Binding Converter, FallbackValue=Content}" Margin="3,0,0,0" HorizontalAlignment="Left" FontSize="16" Foreground="#FF838383" />

                <TextBlock x:Name="time" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="2" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="2h" Margin="0,0,3,0" VerticalAlignment="Center" TextAlignment="Right" Foreground="#FFC1C1C1" FontSize="16" />
            </Grid>
        </DataTemplate>
    </UserControl.Resources>

    <Grid>
        <ListView x:Name="listView" Margin="0" FontSize="16" ItemTemplate="{StaticResource FullItem}"/>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

It's just *ListView* with custom *ItemTemplate* and it looks like this: [image: 1]

I would like to move my 3rd column ("2h" text on screen) way to the right and be  aligned with it. *HorizontalAlignment* doesn't work.

As far as I've read this should work. My 1st column is set to Auto so it'll get Width based on content which in my case is always 55 (45 image width + margins). 3rd column is also set to auto and 2nd column is set to *1** (default) so it should get all left space. But it doesn't. For now it seems to work like there is 3 times Auto.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Modify the Grid in your **DataTemplate** and set the **HorizontalAlignment** Property to **"Stretch"**

Add to your List the **ItemContainerStyle**.  Set the **HorizontalAlignment** property to **"Stretch"**

```
<UserControl
x:Class="UWA.Views.LastActivities"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:local="using:UWA.Views"
xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
mc:Ignorable="d"
d:DesignHeight="300"
d:DesignWidth="400">
<UserControl.Resources>
    <DataTemplate x:Key="FullItem">
        <Grid HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                <ColumnDefinition />
                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition />
                <RowDefinition />
                <RowDefinition />
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>

            <Image x:Name="icon" Grid.Row="0" Grid.RowSpan="3" Grid.Column="0" Height="45" Width="45" VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="5" Source="ms-appx:///Assets/Square44x44Logo.png"/>

            <TextBlock x:Name="title" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="{Binding Title, FallbackValue=Title}" Margin="3,0,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Center" FontWeight="Bold" FontSize="21.333" />
            <TextBlock x:Name="description" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="{Binding Description, FallbackValue=Description}" Margin="3,0,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Center" FontSize="18.667" FontWeight="Bold" Foreground="#FF838383" />
            <TextBlock x:Name="content" Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="1" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="{Binding Converter, FallbackValue=Content}" Margin="3,0,0,0" HorizontalAlignment="Left" FontSize="16" Foreground="#FF838383" />

            <TextBlock x:Name="time" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="2" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="2h" Margin="0,0,3,0" VerticalAlignment="Center" TextAlignment="Right" Foreground="#FFC1C1C1" FontSize="16" />
        </Grid>
    </DataTemplate>
</UserControl.Resources>

<Grid>
    <ListView x:Name="listView"  Margin="0" FontSize="16" ItemTemplate="{StaticResource FullItem}">
        <ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
            <Style TargetType="ListViewItem">
                <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch" />
            </Style>
        </ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
    </ListView>
</Grid>
```